# I need guidance to design a MySql database

Tags: database, relational

Please, I need some help to design a database (as better as posible). I have a set of products made with diferent sizes and customers can create Orders asking for many products and variables quantities of each of their available sizes.

My doubt es which of the following schemas is better?:

1.- Create a table of Products, create a table of Product Sizes, create a table of Orders and create a table for each quantity requiered. For example see the following draft tables (only main fields are shown)

### Products

productCode,description

### ProductSizes

productCode,productSizeDescription

### Orders

orderNumber,orderDate

### OrderDetail

orderNumber,productCode,productSizeDescription,quantityRequired

2.- Create a table of products with multiple fields to define all available product sizes, create a table of Orders with multiple fields to store all quantities required for product size. For example see the following draft tables (only main fields are shown):

### Products

productCode,description,productSize1,productSize2,productSize3,...,productSizeN

### Orders

orderNumber,orderDate,productCode,productSize1,requiredQuantity1,productSize2,requiredQuantity2,produtSize3,requiredQuantity3,...,productSizeN,requiredQuantityN

First approach seems to me the most relational, but their disadvantage is that I need many small records only for the quantities for each product size required.

The second one, is not completely relational but requires only one big record to store all the information regarding to the Order and the quantities required by one product at a time.

I think is not relevant but I plan to use MySql database.

I hope some can guide me to decide wich schema is better or maybe suggest another one.

Thanks in advance, and I apologize for may poor english!

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is best.  Having "many small records" is preferred in a relational database and is not a drawback.